# Result is NaN when geting the total of two variable that are in 2 different function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Why am I getting a NaN result when accessing a variable on 2 different function?

**My code**

```
    var n_standard = 0;
    var n_quad = 0;
    var totalQuad;
    var totalStandard;
    var total = totalStandard + totalQuad;
    function standardRoom(){
      n_standard = n_standard + Number($("#selectBoxStandard").val());
      var xSumStandard = Number($("#n_adultStandard").val()) + Number($("#n_childrenStandard").val());
      totalStandard = {{$availableRooms[0]['nightRate'] * $n_nights }} * n_standard;

      if ($('select#selectBoxStandard option').length > 1 && Number($("#selectBoxStandard").val()) !== 0) {
        $('#selectBoxStandard').find("option:nth-last-child(-n+" + $('#selectBoxStandard').val() + ")").remove();
            $("#roomDetailStandard ul").html('<li><strong>Standard Room - Regular Online Rate</strong> <strong><a href="javascript:removeStandard()" class="pull-right" style="color:red"><u>remove</u></a></strong></li>'+
            '<li class="pull-right"><h4 style="color:darkorange">PHP ' + totalStandard + '</h4></li>'+
            '<li>Number of night(s): {{$n_nights}} </li>'+
            '<li>Number of person(s): ' + xSumStandard + '</li>'+
            '<li class="hr">Number of room(s): '+ n_standard +'</li><hr />'
          );
          $("#totals ul").html('<li>Total:'+ total +'</li>');
          return totalStandard;


      }else {
        alert("Select No. of rooms");
      }
    }

       function quadRoom(){
        n_quad = n_quad + Number($("#selectBoxQuad").val());
       var xSumQuad = Number($("#n_adultQuad").val()) + Number($("#n_childrenQuad").val());
       totalQuad = {{$availableRooms[1]['nightRate'] * $n_nights}} * n_quad;

      if ($('select#selectBoxQuad option').length > 1 && Number($("#selectBoxQuad").val()) !== 0) {
         $('#selectBoxQuad').find("option:nth-last-child(-n+" + $('#selectBoxQuad').val() + ")").remove();
             $("#roomDetailQuad ul").html('<li><strong>Quad Room - Regular Online Rate</strong> <strong><a href="javascript:removeQuad()" class="pull-right" style="color:red"><u>remove</u></a></strong></li>'+
                '<li class="pull-right"><h4 style="color:darkorange">PHP ' + totalQuad + '</h4></li>'+
                '<li>Number of night(s): {{$n_nights}} </li>').append('<li>Number of person(s): ' + xSumQuad + '</li>'+
                '<li class="hr">Number of room(s): '+ n_quad +'</li><hr />'
              );
              $("#totals ul").html('<li>Total:'+ total +'</li>');
              return totalQuad;

      }else {
          alert("Select No. of rooms");
      }
    }


<div  class="button-style-1" style="padding-bottom:80px" style="padding-bottom:40px"><a href="javascript:standardRoom()" ><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i><span class="mobile-visibility">BOOK</span></a></div>
<div class="button-style-1" style="padding-bottom:80px" style="padding-bottom:40px"><a href="javascript:quadRoom()" ><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i><span class="mobile-visibility">BOOK</span></a></div>
```

I tried to return the **totalStandard** and **totalQuad** then add them together in **total**, then output them back inside the function. I'm missing something here, I'm new to javascript so I need some help

Comment: Is some code missing? Where do you call the functions? Also if it's AJAX, JavaScript will continue to execute code while waiting... Giving you nothing to do math with. Best bet is either to implement callbacks when both values are ready or promises (don't the same thing)

Comment: My bad, I added the button that calls the function

Comment: @Doug What do you mean by that? Can you give me an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  n_standard = n_standard + Number($("#selectBoxStandard").val());
  var xSumStandard = Number($("#n_adultStandard").val()) + 
  Number($("#n_childrenStandard").val());
  totalStandard = {{$availableRooms[0]['nightRate'] * $n_nights }} * n_standard;
```

This block of code and where you calculate totalQuad, should be surrounded by number checking functions to be sure that variables are numbers. For example, to be sure that everytime you took only numbers, you can check `if($.isNumeric($availableRooms[0]['nightRate'])){.......}` . If any variable is non number, then the result would be NaN. So please check every number variable before mathematical operation.
Edit: `var totalQuad;
    var totalStandard;
    var total = totalStandard + totalQuad; totalStandard=9; 
    console.log("result="+total);`
This will result in NaN, as I dont define totalQuad variable here. If you initialize both variables to 0 at first, that will work.
**2nd EDIT:**

```js
    var totalQuad;
    var totalStandard;
    var total = totalStandard + totalQuad;
    function standardRoom(){
      totalStandard=9;
    }

       function quadRoom(){
        totalQuad=5;
    }

    function Total()
    {
      console.log(totalStandard);
      console.log(totalQuad);
      console.log(total); // THIS will RESULT IN NaN, as WHEN Total variable initialized, totalStandard and totalQuad are not initialized then. Latter initialization doesn't reinitialize total value
      console.log("Total="+(totalStandard*totalQuad));
    }
```

```html
<div  class="button-style-1" style="padding-bottom:80px" style="padding-bottom:40px"><a href="javascript:standardRoom()" ><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i><span class="mobile-visibility">BOOK</span></a></div>
<div class="button-style-1" style="padding-bottom:80px" style="padding-bottom:40px"><a href="javascript:quadRoom()" ><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i><span class="mobile-visibility">BOOK</span></a></div>
<div class="button-style-1" style="padding-bottom:80px" style="padding-bottom:40px"><a href="javascript:Total()" ><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i><span class="mobile-visibility">Total</span></a></div>
```

Comment: Please see the edit. You add two variables, an from one button click it actually gets on variable value, either totalStandard or totalQuad, not both. As you not initialize both the variables in declaration, the result is NaN.

Comment: What do you mean by that? I did the initialize by 0. But everytime I click the total is not changing. Can you give me an example

Comment: One more point, you call one function from your anchor tag click, that means you get either standard or quad variable, not both.

Comment: I'm not following, I have 2 anchor tag, that each calls different function. And both of them have different variable. I want to add the variable and output the total of both room

Comment: Your problem now laid in the comments 2nd Edit section. Please see that you have calculate total before initializing two variables, thats your problem. Try to calculate total after initialization of two variables.